# How to train Numpy-based data on GPU?

Tags: python, machine-learning, gpu

Because of the huge amount of data, I want to train my data on GPU. My model is also based on Numpy. How can I modify the data and model to speed up my calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Numpy does not have native support GPU. However, you can use library like Numba, which is utilized for big datasets and GPU usage.

Comment: Thank you, I converted numpy-based data into tensor before, and inherited my model from torch.nn, and finally successfully run on GPU, but the speed is much slower than before on CPU, what is the problem?

Comment: @Cro Don't forget to initialize your device first    ` # device
    if torch.cuda.is_available():        
        device = torch.device('cuda')
    else:
        device = torch.device('cpu')  ` and pass the device to your dataloaders and model.